# What's the difference between "for" &"by" in the sentence —"Can you do it for(by) tomorrow?"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, difference

Can you do it **for** tomorrow? Vs Can you do it **by** tomorrow?

**Can you do it for tomorrow?** —From Collins dictionary

Why I should choose "for" in place of "by"??

Comment: Both work, but **by** gives you all day tomorrow to finish it. **For** suggests you have it ready before tomorrow even begins. Both are a bit undefined.

Comment: In both cases, the time of day will depend on the context. For a particular class, meeting, or officially specified deadline. One difference is that "by" often expresses the last possible time, while "for" suggests there's no value in doing it earlier. (Although I can't find dictionary references that are sufficiently precise.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say, *"Can you do it for tomorrow?"*, you're asking if the action can be completed in preparation for tomorrow. It implies that the task should be completed before tomorrow arrives, perhaps to ensure that something is ready or available for tomorrow.

When you say, *"Can you do it by tomorrow?"* sets tomorrow as the deadline for completing the task. It emphasizes that the action needs to be finished no later than tomorrow.

The choice between **"for"** and **"by"** depends on the specific context and what you want to convey.

- Use "for" if you're focused on preparing something in advance for tomorrow.
- Use "by" if you're emphasizing meeting a deadline no later than tomorrow.

Comment: I would also say that "for" would generally indicate that the deadline is the beginning of the day, where "by" would tend to mean at the end of the day.